# Oracle: How to get max value for each item in list

Tags: oracle, select, max, sqlplus

I have a very large table that I need to retrieve data from. The table looks like this:

```
A        B            C        D
1        foo          4        q
1        fool         2        p
1        fools        13       a
2        pho          5        d
3        phone        14       g
3        phones       6        f
```

I'm trying to run something like:

```
select max(B) from table where A = 1 union
select max(B) from table where A = 2 union
.
.
.
select max(B) from table where A = 50000;
```

What I want is to get:

```
1 -> fools
2 -> pho
3 -> phones
```

I have about 50,000 records to run this query for.
This above approach theoretically works (I tried on a small subset), but I think it's inefficient to have one select query for each of the 50000 values.
This also resulted in a process out of memory error.

Is there a way I can run this in a single query? 
I tried:

```
select max(B) from table where A in (first group of 1000) union
select max(B) from table where A in (1000...2000) union
.
.
.
select max(B) from table where A in (40000...50000)
```

But this gives me only one max value per select query (and I understand why)
What I really want is 50000 max values.

Is there a way for me to get the value of max(B) for each item in the list if I use

```
select max(B) from table where A in (...)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to use `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
select A, max(B)
from table
group by A
order by A
```

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: That worked, thank you!
I needed to do :

`select A, max(B)
from table
group by A
union
select A, max(B)
from table
group by A
order by A`